# My Inkjet printer isn't printing correct results from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: print-design, transparency

Using an [Epson L805](https://www.epson.com.sg/For-Home/Printers/Ink-Tank/Ink-Tank-System-Printers/Epson-L805-Wi-Fi-Photo-Ink-Tank-Printer/p/C11CE86501), I'm having some issue with transparency when I print directly from Illustrator.

When I print the below image, you can see that the ellipse shape clearly [the color of the ellipse is darker]. What I wanted in the print was what is displayed on the screen where the ellipse "fades" into the background color to mimic a shadow effect.

Below is the Screen snapshot :

[image: Screen snapshot]

Below is the Print out snapshot :

[image: Printout snapshot]

I tried Flatten Transparency feature in Illustrator but result is the same.

Comment: The word you're looking for, btw, is **ellipse**, which is a flattened circle. An eclipse is when the moon gets in the way of the sun.

Comment: Is this an inkjet print?  What image mode are you using? CMYK or RGB?  Home/office inkjet printers can't handle CMYK images generally. They are only set up to print RGB image files. You could also try saving as PDF, then print it using Adobe Reader.

Comment: This is not a transparency issue and certainly has nothing to do with the moon. The particular printer being used may not be prepared to handle this type of effects, as Billy is saying. Try rasterizing the 'eclipse'.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. Sorry for the poor mistake/poor language. I am designing the work in CMYK and and to make sure, I had also convert it to CMYK under "edit color". The printer I used is Epson L805, which I think can manage CMYK. Sorry for not being detail, but I also did save into PDF first, and then print out from Adobe PDF, but the result were the same. Only when i export to TIFF or JPG, it will works because the color of the "red" background become darker like " ellipse's red"  which is not ideal.

Comment: I also did rasterize , the effect is same as above which is that when I print it out, the red background become darker like the " ellipse's red" , but on the screen it is showing the same as "screen snapshot" .

Comment: @CmCc - jpegs are RGB. That's why it works. Export as an RGB PDF, and print it using Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Epson L805](https://www.epson.com.sg/For-Home/Printers/Ink-Tank/Ink-Tank-System-Printers/Epson-L805-Wi-Fi-Photo-Ink-Tank-Printer/p/C11CE86501) is a *standard*, low-end, end-user, inkjet printer. It is not capable of CMYK nor does it have a Postscript level 3 RIP. In short, it's nothing overly special and its *not* designed for use with high-end professional-level software such as Adobe Illustrator. It's a "mom & pop" printer, designed to print things an average user would print - internet pages, emails, Word documents, etc. - Mostly text-based content or random jpg/png images, not vector illustrations.

- Without a RIP, your Inkjet printer **needs** to be sent **RGB** data. It has *no clue* what CMYK color data even is. So, if you send CMYK data, the printer doesn't understand it and converts the color to RGB so it *can* understand.... then it converts it again to CcYyMmK for output. **Always send RGB color data if there is no RIP**.
- Printing directly from Adobe Illustrator **requires a Postscript level 3 RIP** if you wish the print to be based off the *vector* data in Illustrator. Without a RIP, Illustrator prints the low-resolution raster preview image, because the printer isn't capable of understanding the postscript vector data.

Considering both items above, printing CMYK artwork from Illustrator will result in a *low resolution* print after *two* color conversions --- this *often* results in unexpectedly poor results.

**For best results when printing from Adobe Illustrator using a low-end inkjet printer** -- Save your AI file as an RGB PDF, then print the PDF from Acrobat/Reader. Acrobat/PDF is a software RIP and will process the vector data into a high-quality raster preview for printing.

Comment: Thank you Scott  very much for the advise and information. Noted, I will send CMYK data for professional print shop and RGB for this particular printer. Thanks everyone for looking into this .